# Containers for Windows

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualization

I need to check different files with multiple (15 - 20) anti-viruses on a single Windows machine.

I want to automate this process. Right now I'm unable to install all of these anti-viruses due to conflicts between them.

Could you please suggest some container technology for Windows platform (like Docker for example) where each antivirus can be installed in a separate container?

Is there any better way to solve this task?

Comment: This site is for programming (code) or programmers tools related questions. The [help] has more information regarding the types of question that are (and are not) appropriate to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [herdProtect](https://www.herdprotect.com/) (which according to their website is powered by 68 anti-malware engines in the cloud) or SecureAPlus which follows a similar pattern.

Also for small and manageable file sizes you can check virusTotal.com which is an online service which utilises many malware engines to check the uploaded files for any infections.

Multiple antiviruses running on the same machine is highly discouraged as even in the case of a distrubuted solution (VM's, dockers etc) they will sap the host machine from its strength and resources (memory,cpu, hdd i/o etc)
You can have a look a this old kaspersky blogpost:
https://blog.kaspersky.com/multiple-antivirus-programs-bad-idea/2670/

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is it possible to specify a single concrete file to scan with herdProtect ?

Comment: Hi! You are welcome, If i understand correctly what you mean by saying "concrete" the anwer is yes. You can also check their community q&a    here-> https://www.herdprotect.com/community.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use full-virtualization technology, such as VMWare (WS or ESX), Hyper-V, VirtualBox. The first two could be controlled by scripts. Antivirus software is special that it requires a deep Ring0 access of computer, which can't be done with app-virtualizer like Sandboxie.